# undefined response, ajax is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, vb.net, jquery-plugins

I'm Very Green when it comes to the Front End Development, I'm trying to Insert Data using Modal, I have two text boxes the first is code and the second is name..
I need them to be unique:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("codeNotUsed", function (value, element) {
                    var response;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Profile_ValidatieProfileCode.ashx",
                        data: { code: $('#txtCode').val() },
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            response = eval(data);
                        }
                    });
                    alert(response);
                    return response;

                }, "Code already used");

 $.validator.addMethod("nameNotUsed", function (value, element) {
                    var response;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Profile_ValidateProfileName.ashx",
                        data: { name: $('#txtName').val() },
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            response = eval(data);
                        }
                    });

                    return response;

                }, "Name already used");
```

the content of one of the .ashx files:

```
 Imports System.Web
 Imports System.Web.Services

 Public Class Profile_ValidateProfileName
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

    Dim name = context.Request.Form("name")

    Try
        Dim type = DataFactory.Instance.GetProfileByName(UserIdentity.ClientConfig.ConnectionString, name)

        If IsNothing(type) Then
            context.Response.Write("true")
        Else
            context.Response.Write("false")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        context.Response.Write("false")
    End Try


End Sub

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

HTML Code:

```
 <form id="InputForm" name="InputForm" action="javascript:void(0);" novalidate="novalidate"><div id="InputFormContent">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Code</label>
                    <div class="icon-addon">
                        <input id="txtCode" name="txtCode" class="form-control required" maxlength="10">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div class="icon-addon">
                        <input id="txtName" name="txtName" class="form-control required" maxlength="30">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The unique validation is not working and I thing that's the ajax code is not working well, the alert gives me 'Undefined'..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the alert statement was executed before success function is even called, executing the alert statement after ajax request is done is working better in this case:
   The Code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("codeNotUsed", function (value, element) {

                    var response;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Profile_ValidatieProfileCode.ashx",
                        data: { code: $('#txtCode').val() },
                        async: false,
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(error)
                        }
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        response = eval(data);
                        alert(response); // this will give true or false accourding to server response
                    });
                    return response;


                }, "Code already used");

                $.validator.addMethod("nameNotUsed", function (value, element) {


                        var response;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Profile_ValidateProfileName.ashx",
                            data: { name: $('#txtName').val() },
                            async: false,
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(error)
                            }
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            response = eval(data);
                            alert(response); // this will give true or false accourding to server response

                        });

                        return response;
                    }, "Name already used");
```

Answer (score 0):

your calling ajax is invalid, because you must call ajax first and after done, check result and call *&.validator.addMethod*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Profile_ValidatieProfileCode.ashx",
    data: { code: $('#txtCode').val() }
}).done(function (data) {
    var response = eval(data);
    alert(response);
    $.validator.addMethod("codeNotUsed",function (value, element) { return response;}, "Code already used");
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Profile_ValidateProfileName.ashx",
    data: { name: $('#txtName').val() }
}).done(function (data) {
    var response = eval(data);
    alert(response);
    $.validator.addMethod("nameNotUsed",function (value, element) { return response;}, "Name already used");
});
```